# mql4: how to disable expert trading if it first run

Tags: mql4

I made an <kbd>ExpertAdvisor</kbd>, which opens an order if a price is getting higher or lower over a value of the past day.

Backtesting was fine, but problem is when I put this Expert on an `MT4.Graph` ( a live currency pair ), it opens an order immediately, because the current value of price, when I started the Expert, had greater or lower value than a max of past day.

I need a condition: 
do not start trade if a price is greater or lower than any of extremums of the past day and it is the first Expert running on current currency pair.

Comment: Always paste your code (or what you have tried), so that others will be able to give more concrete answers to your question.  Otherwise, it will end up as a discussion only.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a boolean variable that is initialized to FALSE. Then, before opening the order in the code, check for the value of that variable. The first time it will be FALSE, so your condition is not met and you don't open the order. Immediately set it to TRUE and adjust previous day min/max values accordingly.

On the next iteration it should then open your trade according to new scenario of previous date low/high.

Also, please do have a look to the IsExpertEnabled function here: http://docs.mql4.com/check/isexpertenabled

For further support on Server or Client side MT4 you can contact me via www.mt4software.com or Skype ID: mt4software